# how to find duplicated libs and version conflicting classes using Memory Analyzer Tool

Tags: java, visualvm, eclipse-memory-analyzer

IS Memory Analyzer Tool allows to  find duplicated libs, classes and version conflicting classes present in the given input application

Answer (score 1):

See this if it helps and I Didnt use it though

http://community.bonitasoft.com/effective-way-fight-duplicated-libs-and-version-conflicting-classes-using-memory-analyzer-tool

Comment: thank u for link @kma i swa the link but not able to find the flow Query browser->Java basics->Duplicated classes:

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a problem with different Java versions.

A long story short: If JDK is outdated re-install it, and delete Java executables from C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Firstly, I want to tell you that I have multiple versions of Java on my computer. My JDK is 32-bit because of some drivers not running with 64-bit Java. Also, I have both 32-bit and 64-bit JRE installed, the latter for better performance for Java games.

My JDK was version 7, update 40. The VisualVM was so also that version. However, my JRE with auto updates was version 7, update 45.

java -version told me it was version 45 (which it was), so I didn't think the problem was there.

Then, I checked the versions via Control Panel. I now knew my JDK was outdated, so I uninstalled it and redownloaded it.

Uninstalling removed Java from the system path, so jvisualvm wouldn't run. I added it to the path. Now both the app and VisualVM ran normally, but still the problem persisted.

The final problem was that the system was using the java.exe from C:\Windows\System32 instead of the JDK one. By the date it seemed to be the latest one, but maybe it was that the JRE was installed in a different location that the VisualVM (= the JDK).

Finally, I just deleted the Java executables in both C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64.